# while loop does -1 (mysql_fetch_assoc)

Tags: php, while-loop

to be short and simple: my PHP 
`while ($R = mysql_fetch_asoc($sql)` result does the loop -1... 
So when i've got 4 results it only shows 3, 
does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: is $sql the result of `mysql_query("query")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common cause of this is because you are calling a `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)` before the first while.

Like this:

```
$firstRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
while ($R = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) {
   //> Dataset with -1 row
}
```

Fix with:

```
mysql_data_seek($query,0);
while ($R = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) {
```

Comment: well,... you're absolutely correct. but i need the one before this one as well... :S so how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

complementing @yes123 answer:

```
$R = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
// code that needs that first call to mysql_fetch_assoc()

do {
 //code
} while (($R = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));
```